# Dynamic Programming in Android for displaying Location Traveled

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, textview, dynamic-programming

How to display the time and locations traveled dynamically in a textview???...

For each travel it should create new textview and display the traveled time and location...

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your locationChanged() method.
you can link there to your textviews for time and distance.